# How to use a Github .py file on a jupyter notebook stored locally

Tags: python-3.x

I have a locally stored jupyter notebook  in which I would like to use the .py file here : 
https://gist.github.com/YohanObadia/b310793cd22a4427faaadd9c381a5850#file-knn_impute-py

Can I do that ? Can I do that without downloading the .py file on my computer ?

I tried :

%load https://gist.github.com/YohanObadia/b310793cd22a4427faaadd9c381a5850#file-knn_impute-py

but it returned a cell filled with the html formatted code in the .py file.

What I would like  to do is to invoke the functions in the code displayed at the url https://gist.github.com/YohanObadia/b310793cd22a4427faaadd9c381a5850#file-knn_impute-py without having to download the .py file corresponding to the url.

Comment: You want the raw format https://gist.githubusercontent.com/YohanObadia/b310793cd22a4427faaadd9c381a5850/raw/dfb409baf4042d78ea11bfc333015b677302ec71/knn_impute.py

Comment: Not bad but all the code is replicated in a cell. I would prefer to import the needed functions.